# Is there any php/sql wrapper for google charts

Tags: php, mysql, google-visualization

I would like to add to my website some reporting using Google charts.
The report generation would be using MySql and PHP.
Is there already any library helping to do that or do I have to reinvent the wheel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://code.google.com/p/gchartphp/) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: That's a start indeed, but I would prefer something where I can inject SQL query straight away. I'll wait for any other answer.